# use trial with gem paypal-sdk-rest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I have my site in ruby on rails and for subscription payments I am using the paypal paypal-sdk-rest gem. But I need the first payment to have a lower value and then the next payment to have the normal value so that users can subscribe and test the subscription. I have been reading in the paypal api and a trial with a lower value can be applied. Is it possible to apply trial to the paypal gem paypal-sdk-rest? this is my code of how I create the plans:

```
  def creacion_planes
    
    plan = Plan.new({
      :name => 'Monthly $20',
      :description => '$20 plan (monthly charge)',
      :type => 'infinite',
      :payment_definitions => [{
        :name => 'Plan monthly $20',
        :type => 'REGULAR',
        :frequency_interval => '1',
        :frequency => 'MONTH', #WEEK, DAY, YEAR, MONTH.
        :cycles => '0',
        :amount => {
          :currency => 'USD',
          :value => '20.00'
        }
      }],
      :merchant_preferences => {
        :return_url => complete_paypal_checkouts_planes_url,
        :cancel_url => update_plan_url,
        :max_fail_attempts => '0',
        :auto_bill_amount => 'YES',
        :initial_fail_amount_action => 'CONTINUE'
      }
    })

    # Create plan
    if plan.create
      # Plan update activation object
      plan_update = {
        :op => 'replace',
        :path => '/',
        :value => {
          :state => 'ACTIVE'
        }
      }

      # Activate plan
      if plan.update(plan_update)
        puts("Billing plan activated with ID [#{plan.id}]")
        redirect_to success_payment_path(:plan_id => plan.id, :plan => "plan_mensual20")
      else
        logger.error payment.error.inspect
      end
    else
      logger.error payment.error.inspect
    end
  end
```

And this is my code of how I create the agreement:

```
  def create
    agreement = Agreement.new({
      :name => params[:name],
      :description => params[:description],
      :start_date => (Time.now + 20*60).utc.iso8601, #'2020-04-26T23:00:04Z' (Time.now + 1.days).utc.iso8601
      :plan => {
        :id => params[:plan_id]
      },
      :payer => {
        :payment_method => 'paypal'
      }
    })


    if agreement.create
      redirect = agreement.links.find{|v| v.rel == "approval_url" }.href
      redirect_to redirect
    else
      logger.error agreement.error.inspect
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use that old paypal-ruby-sdk. It is obsolete and uses an old version of billing plans, which is not compatible with the current subscriptions API.

Instead, integrate the subscriptions API via direct HTTPS calls. Here is the guide: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/

An example with a trial period is provided.